# Warning about window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I having a warning like this in my debugger, What does this mean?

`Warning: Attempt to present <RootViewViewController: 0x134ce9c0> on <MovieViewController: 0xa967290> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

I also make the `MovieViewController` as the initial view controller in Storyboard, I am also using ARC.

NOTE: This doesnt appear when I add two `[super viewDidLoad];` 1 in the middle in lowest part of the `viewDidLoad`,which is wrong.

Here is my implementation of the `MovieViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gameopening" ofType:@"m4v"];
    self.moviePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    [self.moviePlayer play];

    // Create and configure AVPlayerLayer
    AVPlayerLayer *moviePlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.moviePlayer];
    moviePlayerLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    moviePlayerLayer.position = CGPointMake(515,385);
    moviePlayerLayer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    moviePlayerLayer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    moviePlayerLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    moviePlayerLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.80;

    // Add perspective transform

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:moviePlayerLayer];    

    [self performSelector:@selector(loadingView) withObject:nil afterDelay:33.0];  
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIImageView *loadingView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
        loadingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Load.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(mainV) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];  
    }

}
-(void)loadingView{

        UIImageView *loadingView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];  
        loadingView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Load.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(mainV) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];  

}
-(void)mainV {

        moviePlayer = nil;
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainViewController"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];   
}
```

Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The `viewDidLoad` method is called when the `view` of your ViewController is loaded into memory. But by that time, the `view` is not on screen yet (so it has not been added as a `subview` of any other `view` or `window`, a.k.a it is not in the view hierarchy).

You should wait for the view to be on screen to present your `MovieViewController`.
Move your code in the `viewDidAppear:` method instead and `viewDidLoad` and you should be OK.

Comment: Oh wait, still produces the warning. :(

Comment: when I `handleTapGesture` it produces this: `Warning: Attempt to present <RootViewViewController: 0xaa6f7b0> on <MovieViewController: 0xa93a7f0> while a presentation is in progress!`

Comment: Superman, did you resolve this gesture generated warning?  I have the very same issue

Comment: what if you have to show a view on button click which is not there in window hierarchy?

Comment: Then simply `addSubview:` it.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be used for this purpose. It is earlier than viewDidAppear.