# ViewController hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scenario like this:
I have a `MovieViewController` it serves as my intro for my app(It is the Initial View Controller in my storyboard). Its goes to another view controller named `MenuViewController` either by:

- Movie Ends
- Detected Touch

So the sequence now is this:
`MovieViewController` ----->  `MenuViewController`  ---> (Then three buttons corresponding to different Views)

According to my older question here: [Warning about window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704984/warning-about-window-hierarchy)

I correspond to the answer and edit my code, but still the error occurs in my debugger.

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

It still occurs several times, Is there a way to make the `MenuViewController`  the main view after `MovieViewController` is shown? or dismiss/ remove it after the movie ends/shown.

Thanks for your guide.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt to answer this question I am going to make the assumption that when you say

> main view

You mean root view.

A simple solution is that when you start your app a navigation controller is created which manages the stack of the view controllers. This navigation controller has a root controller which you should set as your `MenuViewController` (This should be the first view controller loaded) as this is the controller you will want to return to. You can present your `MovieViewController` as a view on top of your `MenuViewController` that way when the `MovieViewController` is dismissed you will be presented with the `MenuViewController`.

On a side note, it is generally not good practice in iOS programming to present a splash screen, where a splash screen is a screen with no functional value other than to delay the presentation of the master view while loading and present information regarding the app.

Comment: do you mean by `splash screen` by means of `appdelegate`? Im not presenting it there, its in another view controller. Could you explain a little more about the last piece you said: `On a side note, it is generally not good practice in iOS programming to present a splash screen. ` Because Im kinda new.

Comment: The appdelegate is not something presented to the user, it assists in managing the application level attributes and actions. I have added a brief explanation of what I mean by a splash screen in the answer

Comment: So my app could get rejected by it? But my client wants to have their intro in the app.

Comment: No, it won't be rejected just for that.

Comment: Does you app. pass? or it got rejected?

Comment: @hasan In a company I worked for in the past we submitted an app with a splash screen and it wasn't rejected.

Comment: I meant that warning msg. I don't have splash but I have the warning.

Comment: @hasan in that case I don't know but without wanting to state the obvious you should probably try resolve the problem regardless of whether it is accepted or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your `MenuViewController` initial view controller, and immediately after it is loaded call:

```
[self presentModalViewController:MovieViewController animated:NO];
```

Then when you want to remove `MovieViewController` from the screen just call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in `MovieViewController`.