# Present a viewController with modal after imagePickerController did finished

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to call a view contorller after selecting an image from `imagePickerController` , so I used this code :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    imageEditorView = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController" bundle:nil];
    imageEditorView.mainViewController = self;
    imageEditorView.imageBG = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self presentViewController:imageEditorView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

but debugger gives me this warning :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ImageEditorViewController: 0xaa42320> on
     <ViewController: 0x9b58680> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

and nothing presents !

and if I dissMiss it first debugger gives me this error :

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <ImageEditorViewController: 0xa913980> on
 <ViewController: 0x9b332a0> while a presentation is in progress
```

!

EDITED

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: First delete the image picker then try to present the view controller.

Comment: just post the code of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method please...

Comment: @Momi now just replace didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method with my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code like:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   [self.parentViewController presentViewController:imageEditorView animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: app crashesh with this issue :
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController dismissModalViewController:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b2f3b0`

Comment: @Momi: which ios version you are using ?

Comment: @Momi: that was a typo in my answer, now check the answer

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    imageEditorView = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController" bundle:nil];
    imageEditorView.mainViewController = self;
    imageEditorView.imageBG = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    [self performSelector:@selector(presentPicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


-(void)presentPicture 
{
     [self presentViewController:imageEditorView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: thanks but same issue ! "Warning: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704984/warning-about-window-hierarchy and here i think this is happen bcoz your window not for multiple paged window so... but now it work with this code but something miss  here i think dude..

Comment: @Momi just change the flow of [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; line if not worked it.. just try it and also add delay time which you want but this is best..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to dismiss UIImagePickerController then only you can use presentViewController go for another view controller.

You can use below code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageEditorView = [[ImageEditorViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageEditorViewController" bundle:nil];
imageEditorView.mainViewController = self;
imageEditorView.imageBG = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self presentViewController:imageEditorView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: `Warning: Attempt to present <ImageEditorViewController: 0xa991450> on <ViewController: 0x9b922b0> while a presentation is in progress!`
When I dismiss it !

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `AppDelegate` you have not set your `rootViewController` of your `window`.
so rather than adding `subview` to `window` make the `rootViewController` of your `window`.

Another thing may be your current `viewController` is actually `subview` to another `viewController`.

My suggestion to put `self.window.rootViewController = yourMaincontroller`  in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: xcode automatically put this line of code int appDelegate , doesn't need to add it .